# How to set field `pint.Quantity._magnitude` of existing object?

Tags: python, pint

Using the [pint library](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), I profiled my code and found a bottleneck is creating new `Quantity` objects using the constructor like this:

```py
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
...
quantity = pint.Quantity(-2.5, ureg.kcal / ureg.mol)
quantities[i] = quantity
```

I have a list `quantities` of `Quantity` objects whose size doesn't change. I would like to edit the `Quantity` objects in-place to try to speed this up. Since the units will never change (always will be kcal/mol), I had hoped to be able simply to set the magnitude instead:

```py
quantities[i].magnitude = -2.5
```

However, this results in this error:

```
---> 43 quantities[i].magnitude = -2.5

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I know `Quantity` objects are mutable, so I hope there is some way to edit the `magnitude` attribute, but I can't tell how from the documentation. I don't see a method to do it.

Of course, Python lets you edit "private" fields directly, so I could do this:

```py
quantities[i]._magnitude = -2.5
```

This does speed up the code significantly. But presumably that field is private for a reason, and something might break if I try to set `_magnitude` directly, i.e., perhaps some other derived fields don't get recomputed that should be?

Comment: If the units never change do you need the pints library?

Comment: What I mean is that, for a given `Quantity` object, its units will never change, but I have many `Quantity` objects in the system and they may have different units from each other. So yes, I'd prefer to do this with the pint library if possible.

Comment: If it’s that slow for your use case maybe look into alternatives or write your own unit conversion module if needed? Or you might be able to pre-instantiate a pool of unitary Quantity instances in each unit you’ll need and assign them as you need them, multiplying by a scalar (assuming you can do this) to set the magnitude. But if you have to abuse a library to get it to work for you, it’s probably not the right library for your use case.